# short enums on VC++ 6.0 (or VC++ 2008)?

Tags: visual-c++, enums, short

It would be very convenient to have "short enum" or "char enum" in VC++, as I have seen mentioned elsewhere for GCC etc. Is there some option in VC++ to allow this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
enum name : char
{
    values
}
```

but this is a VC-specific extension.  Not sure if there's standardised support for this in VC.